# Does the import of "main" swf hides the import of loaded swf in action script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, import, flash, swfloader

I have 2 swf-s, **main.swf** and **another.swf**.
main.swf will load another.swf at run-time.
Corresponding classes for them are `Main` and `Another`.
Both of them `import` a common class `Constant`.

The problem is:
If I make changes to class `Constant`, like define a new constant for class `Another`, then I surely wants to compile **another.swf**.
Then, I run **main.swf** and load **another.swf**, BUT the changes of `Constant` are not applied!

In the contrary, I have to re-compile **main.swf** to make the changes applied to **another.swf**.
It looks like since **another.swf** is loaded by **main.swf**, so the `import` also relies on **main.swf**.
When you run **main.swf** first, class `Main` `import` the `Constant` class first, so any upcoming `import` is hidden (or ignored?), is this true?

Is the `import` only executed once, and is executed by the first played **.swf**?

The **.swf** load is done by `flash.display.Loader` class.

Answer (score 1):

When a class is loaded, its fully qualified domain name (pacakge name + class name) is added to a global registry of sorts.  When `main.swf` loads the `Constant` class, the class is cached.  This **registry** is generated at compile time so `main.swf` has the `Contant` class definition cached as it was when it was compiled.

In fact, if you change `Constant`, you can recompile `main.swf` only and see that modified definition is available in `another.swf`.

Comment: That's true!! I can only recompile main.swf to apply changes, this also bothers me. Do you have any official article (adobe's or anyone) that explains all these mechanism? I'd really love to read all the details, thanks!!

Comment: Why this cache behavior bothers me is that, I actually have lots of .swf to be loaded. And if the class is cached, I have to recompile both main and other .swf even though I didnt make any changes to main.

Comment: @MarsonMao Well, consider a global var class as a global include, which forces you to recompile all your projects that use it if you alter it. It's normal.

Comment: Ah, that's right, sorry I didnt make it clear. I didnt make `Main` to `import` `Constant` until I notice this behavior. I put import in Main to avoid recompile of all swfs, but actually I am searching for a better approach, like an external library for `Constant`. And I am searching for the answer of this behavior.

Comment: use a runtime shared library. It makes no sense to compile classes in 2 different files. Or create a lib project with the shared classes, and link the library as external for one of the swf files. I guess you need the classes only at compile time.